# Ruby how do I get an element from two separate array using the same subscript?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am learning Ruby. I have 2 arrays in which I need to get elements from one or the other in coordinated fashion. The elements are each objects of the same class.
Using the `Array.each_with_index` method does get elements from the first array. Now, based upon the content of the object found, I need to get objects at various places in the second array. if I use notation like:

```
x = arrayName[index]
```

It converts x into an array, and the wanted array object is not returned. I suppose if I convert the array into a hash using the subscripts as keys, it might work, but that is UGLY. I am using Windows 7 and Ruby 1.9.3.  The larger question is: Is this correct behavior? Elsewhere it clearly states that expression `arrayName[index]` returns the object at the index. It was a merry chase to discover this, but it seems to clearly be repeatable. Thanks much for any light.

Comment: could you please post what your input data (the 2 arrays) and what you expect as output

Comment: Are you getting the index with `each_with_index`? It should be something like `firstArray.each_with_index { |element,index| ... }`, where `secondArray[index]` should make sense.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you wish to select an element from `array` at a given offset `i`, `array[i]` suffices; you don't need `each_with_index`.  Given the value `array[i]`, you say you, "need to get objects at various places in the second array".  We need the specific rule you are employing here.  The #1 thing you need to do--as @bjhaid's requested--is provide an example with the two arrays, and show the corresponding result you want.  If the way the result is calculated from the arrays is not obvious, explain the calculations.  Do this by editing the question, and don't delay.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something along the lines of this.

```
arr_1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
arr_2 = [1, 2, 3]

arr_1.zip(arr_2)

#=>[["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
```

There are variations on this to get what I think you're going for.  You can use `{item => arr_2[i]}` instead of the block I used above to have them be nested hashes.

Comment: You could also do...
new_array = arr_1.zip(arr_2)

Comment: That's just a re-implementation of `zip`.